# Блоки в mixin pug

Tags: jade, pug

Есть такой миксин для кнопки

```
- var blocks={};

mixin set(key)
  - blocks[key] = this.block

mixin A(buttonClass, buttonText, disabled)
  button.button(class= buttonClass, disabled= disabled)
    span
      if block
        block
        - blocks.left()
        | #{buttonText}
        - blocks.right()
      else
        | #{buttonText}

+A("button_small button_filled", "Кнопка", false)
  +set('left')
    p l
  +set('right')
    p r
```

Этот миксин рабочий, но работает немного не так, как хотелось бы.
Не могу сообразить как поправить.

Задумка такая что set('left') - это для вставки в кнопку, иконку слева.
+set('right') - иконка с права

Если я пишу +set('left') и +set('right') как примере то все ок.
Но если я пишу что то одно, то ошибка.

https://codepen.io/inkshio/pen/YBVOMK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому пригодиться

```
//-
    Миксин кнопок
    buttonClass - стиль кнопки
    buttonText - текст кнопки
    disabled - активная кнопка или нет (true, false)

mixin button(buttonClass, buttonText, disabled)
    //- Для вывода нескольких блоков в миксине
    - var icons={};

    mixin set(key)
        - icons[key] = this.block

    button.button(class= buttonClass, disabled= disabled)
        span.button__content
            if block
                block
                - if (icons.left) {
                    span.button__icon
                        - icons.left()
                - }
                span.button__text
                    | #{buttonText}
                - if (icons.right) {
                    span.button__icon
                        - icons.right()
                - }
            else
                span.button__text
                    | #{buttonText}
```